# Custom ImageView disappears during ScaleAnimation/AnimationSet

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm having a problem with an `AnimationSet` with two `ScaleAnimations`. Basically I have a custom view that extends an ImageView and am trying to add a "expand"/"shrink" animation to it. The user will press a button and animate the image to fill more or less space basically. I'm trying to do this by scaling the image view.

The animation works but when the animation itself is running it basically makes the Image disappear and when it is finished it reappears, scaled. Once the animation set finishes the image appears again scaled properly.

I'm really out of ideas and was wondering if I need to do something before I start the animation? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Code snippet I below:

```
public void animateImageView(View customImageView) {
    ...
    Animation stretchLeft = new ScaleAnimation(left, newLeft, top, newTop);
    Animation stretchRight = new ScaleAnimation(right, newRight, top, newTop);

    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
    set.addAnimation(stretchLeft);
    set.addAnimation(stretchRight);
    set.setDuration(250);
    set.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
    customImageView.startAnimation(set);
    ...
}
```

Comment: what values are you using for left, newleft, top, newTop, etc?

Comment: They are all  within the screen coordinates if that's what you're asking. Usually top is 144, newtop 0, left 600, newLeft 450 for expanding and vice versa for shrinking the image again. These also change based on the screen you're using.

Comment: Note those numbers are scale factors, so they are going to multiply your base value. So on my 85by90dp custom image view, it disappears with those kind of numbers cause the image gets so big (i was testing with like values of 1 and 2). Also your image view is going to be constrained to stay within its parent container (it can't extend beyond that). Also your stretchLeft and stretchRight animation are going to be playing at the same time, so they are going to be kinda fighting each other and also multiplying on top of each other, that might be what you want though...

Comment: Hmm okay. I was definitely using absolute pixels rather than scaling. I changed that but it still didn't seem to help. I am overriding the `onLayout()`, `onMeasure()`, `onDraw()` and `draw()` methods in my custom views, do you think that could have anything to do with it?